# How do find the probability that all digits will occur in a randomly created number.

Tags: probability

The title pretty much sums it up my question.

I've been working with 16 digit numbers because the random number generator I was working with spit out 16 digit numbers, but I would like to know the process for finding the probability for any given length random number which has a length greater than 9.

I brute forced the question and came up with ~7% of the time a random 16 digit number will contain all numbers between 0-9 at least once in any position.

Note I'm assuming the random number can start with 0.  So, `0000000987654321` is a valid random number that contains all the digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine a sequence of 16 random digits, uniformly distributed and chosen independently.  What's the probability that there is no $7$ in it? The 1st digit is a non-7, *and* the 2nd digit is a non-7, *and* the 3rd digit is a non-7, etc. It's $\left(\dfrac{9}{10}\right)^{16}$.  Similarly that's the probability that there is no $6$, etc.

One way to answer the whole question would be to apply the [inclusion–exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle):

There's no 0 *or* there's no 1 *or* there's no 2 *or* $\ldots\ldots$.

This is an inclusive "or".

\begin{align}
& {}\qquad \Pr(\text{no $0$s or not $1$s or no $2$s or }\cdots) \\[10pt]
& = \underbrace{\Pr(\text{no $0$s}) + \Pr(\text{no $1$s}) + \Pr(\text{no $2$s}) + \cdots}_\text{10 terms} \\[8pt]
& \underbrace{{}- \Pr(\text{no $0$s and no $1$s}) - \Pr(\text{no $0$s and no $2$s}) - \cdots\cdots}_\text{45 terms} \\[8pt]
& \underbrace{{}+ \Pr(\text{no $0$s and no $1$s and no $2$s}) + \Pr(\text{no $0$s and no $1$s and no $3$s})+ \cdots\cdots}_\text{120 terms} \\[8pt]
& {} - \text{ etc., etc. } \cdots\cdots \\[12pt]
& = 10\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^{16} - 45\left(\frac{8}{10}\right)^{16} + 120\left(\frac{7}{10}\right)^{16} - \cdots\cdots
\end{align}

Comment: Sorry, but could you point me in the right direction in using the inclusion--exclusion principle.  I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: [Inclusion–exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I did some research before you posted that, and while I think I understand the basics of inclusion-exclusion, I'm not sure how to apply it to this problem.  What do add, then what do I start subtracting?

Comment: @qw3n:  the point is that when you said the number of strings without any digit was $10\cdot 9^{16}$ you counted the strings with no $7$'s and no $6$'s twice, once as missing $7$ and once as missing $6$.  So now you need to subtract them once.